# When I prepend data to an existing page, it doesn't perfom any jQuery actions

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="partition">
    hello
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit">
</div> <!-- partitions ends -->

<!-- this posts the data and prepends the return data to partition div -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function(){
            var content = $('#content').val();
            var contentType = $('input[id=contentType]:checked').val();

            $.post('classes/updateStatus.php', { content: content, contentType: contentType }, function(data)
            {        
                $('#partition').prepend($('<div id="partition">'+data+'</div>').html(data));
            });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(){      
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

The problem with this script is that after prepending the data to partition div, it doesn't perform the necessary action. In this case, it doesn't popup an alert box.

Comment: you are appending a div with a partition id inside of another div with a partition id. the original div should still work, the new one should not due to 1 it doesn't hav eany events bound, and 2, it has a non-unique id.

Comment: For starters you can't have two elements with the same ID. Or rather you can, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: Instead of "Click", use either a "live" or "on" event something like : $('#btn').live("click", function(){ }); or $('#btn').on("click", function(){ });

Comment: This isn't part of your problem, but you are missing closing `});` braces on both of your `$(document).ready()` functions, as well as on your button's `click` function. This is much more apparent when you have proper indentation.

Comment: thnx @Praveen works fine :)...thanks to all the other guys who helped me out....u guys r the best :)

Comment: @Praveen , put that in an answer

Comment: @trBuster: Don't use `.live()`. It is deprecated. Use `.on()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can do something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('#btn').live("click", function(){               
alert("hello");     
});
});
```

(this is old version)

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('#btn').on("click", function(){               
alert("hello");     
});
});
```

(this is in new version)

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

At the first sign - you should close your input tag

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="submit"/>
```

Your JS function dont have closed curly bracke

***[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abaksheyev/9acHx/2/)***

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you did not close the `$(document).ready();` function

Java script should be something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
       var content = $('#content').val();
        var contentType = $('input[id=contentType]:checked').val();

        $.post('classes/updateStatus.php', { content: content, contentType: contentType }, function(data)
        {        
            $('#partition').prepend($('<div id="partition">'+data+'</div>').html(data));
        });                    
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(){      
    alert("hello");
});
})
```